# Cannot chroot mounted volume to reset root password ( hangs )

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos

I am trying to reset the root password on my instance. I boot it in rescue mode and mount the primary disk.

```
fdisk -l
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
sudo chroot /mnt
```

The prompt just hangs here and it never gives me a new prompt so I can passwd and reset it.

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out why it was not successfully chrooting the mounted volume but I fixed it by just manually editing /etc/shadow.

Just generate a new hash & salt using ONE of the below commands:
(they both do the same thing)

```
mkpasswd -m sha-512 PASSWORD SALT
python -c 'import crypt; print crypt.crypt("password", "$6$saltsalt$")'
```

Now edit /etc/shadow with your favorite editor.

You will see a long list of accounts. Find the one corresponding to your user.

admin:$6$IcQdmmXO$GQcrQ3Jrqj8CyTKlBPPMD.8760XEOPpgEjSZX3Q.Ah9uRjmuRqs9c4632vzH3FiIg2flH7VWNbTXfVh04gRQR1:16977:0:99999:7:::

It will look like the above. Paste the hash/salt combo generated by the mkpasswd command in between the first set of :

Example:

admin:newHashHere:16977:0:99999:7:::